# Intel 8086 Insertion Sort: Skipping numbers within the Array

Tags: arrays, assembly, intel, x86-16, insertion-sort

So we're currently studying Intel 8086 Insertion Sort Code that our professor showed us. He wanted us to figure out why the code skips the 0th element within the array and the 3rd element in the array from a code that he had taken from the web.

```
; void isort(int *a, int n)
;   sorts the first n elements of a
;
; Parameters
;   a - pointer to the array
;   n - number of elements to sorts

%define a [ebp + 8]
%define n [ebp + 12]
isort:
  enter 0, 0
  pusha

  mov ecx, 1
  for:
    mov ebx, ecx
    imul ebx, 4
    add ebx, a
    mov ebx, [ebx]

    mov edx, ecx
    dec edx

    while:
      cmp edx, 0
      jl while_quit

      mov eax, edx
      imul eax, 4
      add eax, a

      cmp ebx, [eax]
      jge while_quit

      mov esi, [eax]

      mov dword [eax + 4], esi

      dec edx
      jmp while
    while_quit:

    mov [eax], ebx

    inc ecx
    cmp ecx, n
    jl for

  popa
  leave
  ret
```

And the sample array was {5, 8, 12, 2, 1, 7}. This is more for understanding the 8086 language since we just started a couple days ago, and I was wondering if anyone could explain how and what might be going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Consider what the code will do when `ECX` is 1:

- The `while` loop will be entered with `EBX=8` and `EDX=0`.
- The `jl while_quit` will not be taken, since `EDX` is 0.
- `EBX` is compared to `[EAX]`. That is; 8 is compared to `a[0]`, which is 5, so the `jge while_quit` is taken.
- `mov [eax], ebx` stores 8 at `a[0]`, so your array now contains `{8,8,12,2,1,7}`. Clearly not what you want, since you've lost one of the original elements.

---

Apart from the code's logical flaw, those `imul` instructions are completely unnecessary since you can use scaled indices on the x86. So the sorting code can be simplified to this (I've verified that it sorts the array correctly):

```
mov ecx, 1
for_:
  ; esi = &a[holePos]   
  lea esi,[a + ecx*4]
  ; valueToInsert = a[holePos]
  mov ebx, [esi]

  while_:
    ; Did we reach the beginning of the array?
    cmp esi, OFFSET a
    jle while_quit

    ; valueToInsert < a[holePos-1] ?
    cmp ebx, [esi-4]
    jge while_quit

    ; a[holePos] = a[holePos-1]
    mov eax, [esi-4]
    mov [esi], eax

    ; esi = &a[holePos-1]
    sub esi,4
    jmp while_
  while_quit:

  ; a[holePos] = valueToInsert
  mov [esi], ebx

  inc ecx
  cmp ecx, 6
  jl for_
```

I'm using MASM syntax, but you get the idea.